# C# Connect to Server By Host Name Correctly

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I was trying to connect to a server application I built. However, the annoying part is that the host machine of the server application have a dynamic IP. So, I googled around and found out that I can use `Dns.GetHostAddresses`. But the problem is `Dns.GetHostAddresses` actually gives all the target machine's IP Adress. Recently I used `Dns.GetHostAddresses("Server_Host_Name")[0]`, which gives me the 1st IP address.

The method have worked so far. But I will like to know is there any safer way of doing this? or this method is fine?

Thanks for any reply and answer.

Comment: There is nothing significant about the first address returned in that list. If you want to have a consistent way to connect to a server it would need to have a dedicated IP address.

Comment: Hint: use `var first = Dns.GetHostAddresses("Server_Host_Name").FirstOrDefault()` than you can check against null.

Comment: oh okay thanks for the replies. I think I will try to make the server IP static, as this is intended for LAN only.